# Custom Button to have default upperCase text on child Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a Custom Button which has by default the Text as uppercase.

but a normal `RawMaterialButton` take a child how can I modify it so the text is always uppercase.

this is my button

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class DemoButton extends MaterialButton {

  final BorderRadius borderRadius;

  const DemoButton ({
    this.borderRadius,
    Key key,
    @required VoidCallback onPressed,
    Color textColor,
    Color disabledTextColor,
    Color color,
    Color disabledColor,
    double elevation,
    Widget child,
    EdgeInsetsGeometry padding,
    ShapeBorder shape,
  }) : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  super(
        key: key,
        onPressed: onPressed,
        textColor: textColor,
        disabledTextColor: disabledTextColor,
        color: color,
        disabledColor: disabledColor,
        elevation: elevation,
        child: child,
        padding: padding,
        shape: shape,
      );

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final ButtonThemeData buttonTheme = ButtonTheme.of(context);

    return RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        clipBehavior: clipBehavior ?? Clip.none,
        fillColor: buttonTheme.getFillColor(this),
        textStyle: theme.textTheme.button.copyWith(color: buttonTheme.getTextColor(this)),
        padding: buttonTheme.getPadding(this),
        shape: buttonTheme.getShape(this) == shape ? buttonTheme.getShape(this) : RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
        child: child,
      );
```

this is what i tried but obviously it's wrong.

`child: Text(''.toUpperCase()),`

I also tried an `if` condition as the shape but I cannot generalize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update `build` method. I used `if` condition to check if the child passed is `Text` and if it is, we take `data` from it, assign it to `newChild` and make it `UpperCase`.

```
class DemoButton extends MaterialButton {
  final BorderRadius borderRadius;
  final bool upperCase;

  DemoButton({
    this.borderRadius,
    Key key,
    @required VoidCallback onPressed,
    Color textColor,
    Color disabledTextColor,
    Color color,
    Color disabledColor,
    double elevation,
    Widget child,
    EdgeInsetsGeometry padding,
    this.upperCase = true,
    ShapeBorder shape,
  })  : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
        super(
          key: key,
          onPressed: onPressed,
          textColor: textColor,
          disabledTextColor: disabledTextColor,
          color: color,
          disabledColor: disabledColor,
          elevation: elevation,
          child: child,
          padding: padding,
          shape: shape,
        );

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var newChild = child;
    if (child is Text && upperCase) {
      Text text = child as Text;
      newChild = Text(text.data.toUpperCase(), style: text.style);
    }

    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final ButtonThemeData buttonTheme = ButtonTheme.of(context);

    return RawMaterialButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      clipBehavior: clipBehavior ?? Clip.none,
      fillColor: buttonTheme.getFillColor(this),
      textStyle: theme.textTheme.button.copyWith(color: buttonTheme.getTextColor(this)),
      padding: buttonTheme.getPadding(this),
      shape: buttonTheme.getShape(this) == shape ? buttonTheme.getShape(this) : RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
      child: newChild,
    );
  }
}
```

---

This is how you should use it.

```
DemoButton(
   onPressed: () {},
   color: Colors.blue,
   upperCase: false, // set it to false 
   child: Text(
     "button",
     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.orange),
   ),
 )
```

[image]

Comment: yep that's what I was looking for. Is there a way to make it optional tho? so I am able to use both upper and lower but the default to be upper?

Comment: Didn't think about getting `data` from `Text` - interesting

Comment: @CopsOnRoad sorry this does not change anything. can't turn to lowercase still

Comment: @copsOnRoad can't even change the text color anymore with this approach

Comment: yes, thank you, still not able to change from upper to lower case tho. but the color is working

Comment: @key can you again take a look at last example I edited?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String` instead of `Widget` in your constructor

```
class DemoButton extends MaterialButton {

  final BorderRadius borderRadius;

  DemoButton({ // remove `const` keyword
    this.borderRadius,
    Key key,
    @required VoidCallback onPressed,
    Color textColor,
    Color disabledTextColor,
    Color color,
    Color disabledColor,
    double elevation,
    String text, // change this field
    EdgeInsetsGeometry padding,
    ShapeBorder shape,
  })
      : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
        super(
        key: key,
        onPressed: onPressed,
        textColor: textColor,
        disabledTextColor: disabledTextColor,
        color: color,
        disabledColor: disabledColor,
        elevation: elevation,
        child: Text(text.toUpperCase()),  // and set here `Text` with upperCase
        padding: padding,
        shape: shape,
      );
}
```

Comment: Good Andrey but that would not make the widget flexible. You can then only use `String` not any widget.

Comment: Yes. It can be made more flexible. I just created example with text in uppercase as be written in question